# PHP & MYSQL - Query DB Table to confirm field is in a Column

Tags: php, mysql

I've searched to find a resolution to problem, but the results were too complex, or too simple.

I have a basic login box to my site. I have an LDAP server that I query, to pull in the username's information, i.e. positiontitle.

I have a table named group_id, with a column named title. I want to query the column to find a match of the user's positiontitle from LDAP, in the DB. So, the query will need to include a variable. If there is a match, the user will be directed to a certain page on my site. If no match, go somewhere else. Any suggestions?

This pulls in the info from LDAP

```
    function getEmpInfo(){
    <?php
    $ldap = new WIN_LDAP('DEV');
$empNum = $_REQUEST['employeeNumber'];
$empResults = @$ldap->getEmpInfo($empNum);
$results = $empResults->positiontitle;
    ?>
    }
```

This will query the DB for a match to direct to the correct page

```
    $query = "Select title FROM group_id WHERE title = '$results' ";
    $posResult = mysql_query($query);


    if ($results === $posResult){
    setcookie( md5("name"), md5($_REQUEST['enumber']), time()+3600, "/","", 0);
     header('location: /admin.php');
       } else {
     setcookie( md5("general"), md5($_REQUEST['enumber']), false, "/","", 0);
   header('Location: /general.php');
    }
```

I know the code above does not work, but, it will give you an idea of what I'm trying to do

Comment: Mysql_query returns a handle, not your query results.  You'll need need tO use mysql_num_rows() to get the number of matched rows, and mysql_fetch_assoc() to get each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post Edited!

This should work :)

```
$myResult = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM group_id"); //This will select ALL titles
$matchFound = false;
while ($titles = mysql_fetch_row($myResult)) //This will fetch myResult until the
//last value. It's a sort of foreach.
{ 
    if ($titles[0] == $results) //For each title grabbed, we check if it is equal to
    //the $results variable. I wrote $titles[0] because mysql_fetch_row puts every row
    //fetched in an array, where the indexes represent the columns. We selected only
    //one column, so there is only $titles[0].
        $matchFound = true;
}
if ($matchFound)
    //Here goes the code to execute if you found the match
else
    //You know it
```

Please note that headers must be sent BEFORE displaying any layout on the page, otherwise they will not be sent. Ensure there are no spaces/returns before your php tag because it will cause the headers to not be sent.

Example #1

```
//no space here
<?php
    header (something); //this will be sent
?>
```

Example #2

```
 //space
<?php
    header(something); //this won't be sent
?>
```

Example #3

```
<html>
<?php
    header(something); //this won't be sent neither
?>
```

Comment: $results = $empResults->positiontitle; provides the title of the given enumber. It is not a list

Comment: So, basically, I just want to take the result of $results, which is one title, pulled from the username submitted, and make sure there is a match on the table 'group_id', column 'title', to send to the correct page after login.